# NavigationStack with path doesn't work properly inside UIHostingController

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

When `UIHostingController`'s `rootView` is wrapped in a `NavigationStack`, navigation by means of `NavigationStack`'s `path` doesn't work: Even though a value is appended to the `NavigationPath`, the corresponding view is not pushed.

Curiously enough, if `NavigationStack` is initialized with a non-empty `path`, it shows the stack correctly:

[image: Incorrect behavior of NavigationStack inside UIHostingController]

(On the animation, the screen with the "Show first" button is a `UIViewController`, which modally presents a SwiftUI view wrapped in a `UIHostingController` (the view with the button "Open next".) "Open next" modifies `path` of the view, trying to push another SwiftUI view, with the "Next" text label.

This is a minimal reproducible example, stripped of all irrelevant code:

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

  class NavigationModel: ObservableObject {

    enum Path {
      case second
    }

    @Published var navigationPath = NavigationPath()

  }

  @ObservedObject var navigationModel = NavigationModel()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Show first", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentSecondViewController), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(button)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor), button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)])
  }

  @objc func presentSecondViewController() {
    let view = NavigationStack(path: $navigationModel.navigationPath) {
      Button("Open next") { self.navigationModel.navigationPath.append(NavigationModel.Path.second) }
        .navigationDestination(for: NavigationModel.Path.self) {
          switch $0 {
            case .second:
              SecondView()
          }
        }
    }

    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    present(vc, animated: true)
  }

}

struct SecondView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Next")
  }
}
```

However, the same approach works in the pure SwiftUI: If the root view modally presents another view wrapped in a `NavigationStack`, all modifications of the corresponding `path` result in the expected behavior:

[image: Correct behavior of NavigationStack in pure SwiftUI]

Here's the code of the working example:

```swift
@main struct SwiftUIPlaygroundApp: App {

  class NavigationModel: ObservableObject {

    enum Path {
      case second
    }

    @Published var navigationPath = NavigationPath()

  }

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      Button("Show first") { firstShown = true }
        .sheet(isPresented: $firstShown) {
          NavigationStack(path: $navigationModel.navigationPath) {
            Button("Open next") { navigationModel.navigationPath.append(NavigationModel.Path.second) }
              .navigationDestination(for: NavigationModel.Path.self) {
                switch $0 {
                  case .second:
                    SecondView()
                }
              }
          }
        }
    }
  }
  @State var firstShown = false
  @ObservedObject var navigationModel = NavigationModel()

}

struct SecondView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Next")
  }
}
```

How could I make it work properly inside `UIHostingController`?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: try changing `@ObservedObject` to `let` SwiftUI wrappers serve no purpose in UiKit if you need binding you need to go into a `SwiftUI.View` binding does not work in UIKit,

Comment: Moving `@ObservedObject` into the SwiftUI view indeed makes it work. But it also forces me to move `navigationDestination(for:)` inside the view—this breaks the idea of separating views from navigation. (The view controller from the question is just a minimal example to demonstrate the problem. In reality, instead of the view controller, I have a coordinator class, which presents a `UIHostingController` above UIKit's view controller and handles navigation inside the `UIHostingController`'s root view by manipulating its `NavigationStack`'s `path`.)

Comment: You won’t be able to do that, UIKit and SwiftUI are 2 different frameworks that work very differently SwiftUI depends on DynamicProperty which UIKit can’t use. You can either use UIKit’s UINavigationController to present a series of UIHostingControllers or stick to a pure SwiftUI way of doing things. you are likely going to run into issues interfacing the deeper you go if you decide to force the two frameworks together.

Comment: It's not that I want to force it, of course. It's just I'm working on a rather big UIKit app and gradually migrating to SwiftUI. I was hoping to re-work navigation also gradually, one area of the app at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum) correctly pointed out for me, the problem is in `@ObservedObject`, which doesn't work outside a SwiftUI view. If `NavigationModel` is injected to the `UIHostingController`'s root view, navigation works as expected.

However, it also forces us to move `NavigationStack` and the corresponding `navigationDestination` view modifier inside the view as well. This breaks the idea of separating views from navigation, and SwiftUI views become "aware of each other."

To partially solve the problem of hardcoded navigation, we can inject the destination block from the outside, like this:

```swift
struct FirstView<Destination: View>: View {

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $navigationModel.navigationPath) {
      Button("Open next") {
         self.navigationModel.navigationPath.append(HomeViewController.NavigationModel.Path.second)
      }
        .navigationDestination(for: HomeViewController.NavigationModel.Path.self, destination: navigationDestination)
    }
  }
  @ViewBuilder private let navigationDestination: (HomeViewController.NavigationModel.Path) -> Destination
  @ObservedObject private var navigationModel: HomeViewController.NavigationModel

  init(navigationModel: HomeViewController.NavigationModel, @ViewBuilder navigationDestination: @escaping (HomeViewController.NavigationModel.Path) -> Destination) {
    self.navigationModel = navigationModel
    self.navigationDestination = navigationDestination
  }

}
```

This is not a perfect solution, of course, but it solves the problem of the views being "aware" of each other.

This is the updated code related to the `UIHostingController`:

```swift
@objc func presentSecondViewController() {
  let view = FirstView(navigationModel: navigationModel) {
    switch $0 {
      case .second:
        SecondView()
    }
  }

  let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
  present(vc, animated: true)
}
```